# Fail to install dotnet-symbol for lldb in .netcore3.1

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, centos7

lldb is ok and version is 3.9.0, I want to debug a dump file, So I need to install dotnet-symbol tool.
[image: lldb-version]
When installing dotnet-symbol in centos7, I found that the latest version on nuget.org is only compatible with .NET 6.0, but I couldn't find a version that matches .NET Core 3.1.
[image: ditnet-info]
[image: error_info]

Is there any way to handle this situation?

Comment: How about installing an older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, we need to use older version.

[image]

Try this.

[image]

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-symbol --version 1.0.412101
```